# Warning in logs: Deprecated function CRM_Utils_System::getUrlPath

Tags: logs

We have thousands of the same warning on a 5.38. What should we do about it. Just not care? It fills up the logs and looking for anything else is not easy.

`[warning] Deprecated function CRM_Utils_System::getUrlPath, use CRM_Utils_System::currentPath. Array ( [civi.tag] => deprecated )`

Comment: This is almost the same question as https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/37917/what-should-i-do-about-deprecated-functions

Comment: thanks @Demerit I've read the exchanges. I still feel lost to find in core or in a setting where to fix this (except not showing deprecated functions) :-/

Comment: At [line 1036](https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/blob/02ef1a69ca22ff6d12b2fef9d856669bce1fed55/CRM/Core/Error.php#L1036) insert a line  `CRM_Core_Error::backtrace('backTrace', TRUE);`. Then it might be easier to see where it's coming from, but my guess would be an extension so you could also `grep -r "CRM_Utils_System::getUrlPath" [your-extensions-folder]`

Comment: thanks we'll give a try.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to Demerit, we were able to identify the source file using this command in the console:

```
grep -r "CRM_Utils_System::getUrlPath" /home/ourserver/sitefolder/wp-content/uploads/civicrm/ext
```